# Trying to reverse a string without using string.h library functions in C using pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers, reverse

It returns halfway and shows--Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
This code shows no error or warning also.
Just want to know exactly why is it happening?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void reverse(char*);

int main()
{
char str[200];
printf("Enter a string : ");
scanf("%s",&str);
reverse(str);
printf("Reversed string : %s",str);
}

void reverse(char *p)
{
char temp,*q;
*p=*q;
while(*p!='\0')
{
    q++;
}
while(p<q)
{
    temp=*p;
    *p=*q;
    *q=temp;
    p++;
    q--;
 }
}
```

Comment: `char temp,*q; *p=*q;` - here you are trying to dereference `q`, but you have not assigned any valid value to it. This leads to undefined behavior. There are likely other issues in your code.

Comment: No warnings? Not even *warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'q' used*?

Comment: Surprisingly, it doesn't give any warnings or errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never initialized q. It is pointing to something completely random.

Fix is `char temp, *q = p;`

Comment: Also change the while condition : while (*q != 0) ... You must test what q is pointing to not p.

Answer (score 0):

Did the following changes as answered and added a change also which made the code work.

```
      #include<stdio.h>
      void reverse(char*);
      void main()
       {
         char str[20];
         printf("Enter a string : ");
         scanf("%s",&str);
         reverse(str);
         printf("Reversed string : %s",str);
        }
        void reverse(char *p)
        {
         char temp,*q=p;
         while(*q!='\0')
         {
           q++;
         }
         q--;
         while(p<q)
         {
          temp=*p;
          *p=*q;
          *q=temp;
           p++;
           q--;
         }
        }
```